# How to get Rule Definition from DRL File in BRMS

Tags: drools, kie, drools-guvnor, redhat-brms

Is there a way to get a rule definition from a DRL file in JBOSS BRMS using rest or java API?
I have a Kie server where my container is loaded, can I get the rule file definition from the container using API or REST call.

We are using 6.5.0.Final-redhat-2 version of KIE and 6.4.0.GA version for BRMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no KieServer API to return a DRL resource as of today. If you have the DRL file or the kjar containing the file, you can use the parser API to retrieve the rue definition:

Here are some test cases with examples of how to use the parser to inspect rules:

https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/6.5.0.Final/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/compiler/lang/RuleParserTest.java